# Does align environment (or an alternative) have an option to choose left, center or right alignment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, arrays

I have quite a long set of equations, written in an `array` environment, but I can't seem to get it to split so that it is spread over multiple pages. I could use the `align` environment, but I can't seem to find a left, center or right option, while I would like to use it as in the `array` environment: `\begin{array}{llrcl} ... \end{array}`. This is the LaTeX code:

```
\[
\begin{array}{llrcl}
g_1=\dfrac{f_1}{\norm{f_1}}\\
h_2=f_2-(f_2,g_1)g_1, & g_2=\dfrac{h_2}{\norm{h_2}}, & (g_1,g_2) & = & \dfrac{(g_1,f_2-(f_2,g_1)g_1)}{\norm{h_2}}\\
&&& = & \dfrac{(f_2,g_1)-(f_2,g_1)(g_1,g_1)}{\norm{h_2}}\\
&&& = & 0\\
h_3^1=f_3-(f_3,g_1)g_1, & g_3^1=\dfrac{h_3^1}{\norm{h_3^1}}, & (g_1,g_3^1) & = & \dfrac{(g_1,f_3-(f_3,g_1)g_1)}{\norm{h_3^1}}\\
&&& = & \dfrac{(f_3,g_1)-(f_3,g_1)(g_1,g_1)}{\norm{h_3^1}}\\
&&& = & 0\\
h_3^2=g_3^1-(g_3^1,g_2)g_2, & g_3=g_3^2=\dfrac{h_3^2}{\norm{h_3^2}}, & (g_1,g_3^2) & = & \dfrac{(g_1,g_3^1-(g_3^1,g_2)g_2)}{\norm{h_3^2}}\\
&&& = & \dfrac{(g_1,g_3^1)-(g_2,g_3^1)(g_1,g_2)}{\norm{h_3^2}}\\
&&& = & 0\\
&& (g_2,g_3^2) & = & \dfrac{(g_2,g_3^1-(g_3^1,g_2)g_2)}{\norm{h_3^2}}\\
&&& = & \dfrac{(g_2,g_3^1)-(g_2,g_3^1)(g_2,g_2)}{\norm{h_3^2}}\\
&&& = & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
h_j^1=f_j-(f_j,g_1)g_1, & g_j^1=\dfrac{h_j^1}{\norm{h_j^1}}, & (g_1,g_j^1) & = & \dfrac{(g_1,f_j-(f_j,g_1)g_1)}{\norm{h_j^1}}\\
&&& = & \dfrac{(f_j,g_1)-(f_j,g_1)(g_1,g_1)}{\norm{h_j^1}}\\
&&& = & 0\\
h_j^2=g_j^1-(g_j^1,g_2)g_2, & g_j^2=\dfrac{h_j^2}{\norm{h_j^2}}, & (g_1,g_j^2) & = & \dfrac{(g_1,g_j^1-(g_j^1,g_2)g_2)}{\norm{h_j^2}}\\
&&& = & \dfrac{(g_1,g_j^1)-(g_j^1,g_2)(g_1,g_2)}{\norm{h_j^2}}\\
&&& = & 0\\
&& (g_2,g_j^2) & = & \dfrac{(g_2,g_j^1-(g_j^1,g_2)g_2)}{\norm{h_j^2}}\\
&&& = & \dfrac{(g_2,g_j^1)-(g_j^1,g_2)(g_2,g_2)}{\norm{h_j^2}}\\
&&& = & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
h_j^{j-1}=g_j^{j-2}-(g_j^{j-2},g_{j-1})g_{j-1}, & g_j=g_j^{j-1}=\dfrac{h_j^{j-1}}{\norm{h_j^{j-1}}}, & (g_k,g_j) & = & \dfrac{(g_k,g_j^{j-2}-(g_j^{j-2},g_{j-1})g_{j-1})}{\norm{h_j^{j-1}}}\\
&&& = & \dfrac{\!\!\!\!\!\overbrace{(g_k,g_j^{j-2})}^{\delta_{k,j-1}(g_k,g_j^{j-2})}\!\!\!\!\!-(g_j^{j-2}\!\!\!\!\!,g_{j-1})\overbrace{(g_k,g_{j-1})}^{=\delta_{k,j-1}}}{\norm{h_j^{j-1}}}\\
&&& = & 0
\end{array}
\]
```

where `\norm{...}` stems from the custom command

```
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\ensuremath{\left|\left|{#1}\right|\right|}} % General norm.
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Please complete your code snippet into a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `align*`, which allows breaks by adding `\displaybreak` before an ending `\\`. For the third column, though, it's better to use an inner `aligned` environment, so those parts won't be broken across pages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

% this is much better for defining \norm
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
g_1&=\dfrac{f_1}{\norm{f_1}}
\\
h_2&=f_2-(f_2,g_1)g_1,
 & g_2&=\dfrac{h_2}{\norm{h_2}}, 
 && \!\begin{aligned}[t]
   (g_1,g_2)
   &= \dfrac{(g_1,f_2-(f_2,g_1)g_1)}{\norm{h_2}} \\
   &= \dfrac{(f_2,g_1)-(f_2,g_1)(g_1,g_1)}{\norm{h_2}}\\
   &= 0
   \end{aligned}
\\
h_3^1&=f_3-(f_3,g_1)g_1,
 & g_3^1&=\dfrac{h_3^1}{\norm{h_3^1}},
 && \!\begin{aligned}[t]
   (g_1,g_3^1) 
   &= \dfrac{(g_1,f_3-(f_3,g_1)g_1)}{\norm{h_3^1}}\\
   &= \dfrac{(f_3,g_1)-(f_3,g_1)(g_1,g_1)}{\norm{h_3^1}}\\
   &= 0
   \end{aligned}
\\
h_3^2&=g_3^1-(g_3^1,g_2)g_2,
 & g_3&=g_3^2=\dfrac{h_3^2}{\norm{h_3^2}},
 && \!\begin{aligned}[t]
   (g_1,g_3^2)
   &= \dfrac{(g_1,g_3^1-(g_3^1,g_2)g_2)}{\norm{h_3^2}}\\
   &= \dfrac{(g_1,g_3^1)-(g_2,g_3^1)(g_1,g_2)}{\norm{h_3^2}}\\
   &= 0
   \end{aligned}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works great! Still have to figure out how the left/center/right things works with the align* environment, though.

Thanks a lot!